# How to combine pairwise certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with columns 1x, 2x, ..., 16x, 1y, 2y, ..., 16y. I need to find pairwise combinations of values of x and y columns and store them in a new dataset.

I need to get something like this:

1x 1y

1x 2y

....

1x 16y

...

...

16x 1y

16x 2y

...

16x 16y

Directions (x before y) are important. Pairs like '2y 1x' are not interesting for my research. Also, some values are NaN. I haven't decided what to do with them yet.

My idea is to iterate through columns, but i do not know how exactly to do it in python

Maybe something like

```
new_df=[0]
for i from '1x' to '16x'
for j from '1y' to '16y'
    if value is not NaN then
       new_df=i+j
    else discard
```

I am new in python, so I do not really know the syntax. Please, help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by *Jeff H* is OK in this respect, that it uses *itertools.product*.
But you actually need **values** of particular columns, not their **names**.

I created my solution with such a principle in mind, that the performance
is better if you:

- first generate a list of rows, in a loop for each column pair,
- then (after the loop) create from it the result DataFrame.

Start the code from `import itertools` (will be needed soon).

To make my example short, let's limit the number of *nx* and *ny* columns
to just 3:

```
colNo = 3
```

(in the final version of your code change it back to 16).

For the test run, I prepared a source DataFrame with the following content:

```
    1x   2x   3x   1y   2y   3y
0  1xa  2xa  3xa  1ya  2ya  3ya
1  1xb  2xb  3xb  1yb  2yb  3yb
```

First define a function to generate a list of *x* or *y* column names:

```
def colNames(n, suffix):
    return [ str(col + 1) + suffix for col in range(n) ]
```

Then, to generate a list of source rows, run:

```
rows = []
for cols in itertools.product(colNames(colNo, 'x'), colNames(colNo, 'y')):
    rows.extend(df[list(cols)].values.tolist())
```

And the last step is to create the result DataFrame from these rows:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['x', 'y'])
```

When you `print(result)`, you will get:

```
      x    y
0   1xa  1ya
1   1xb  1yb
2   1xa  2ya
3   1xb  2yb
4   1xa  3ya
5   1xb  3yb
6   2xa  1ya
7   2xb  1yb
8   2xa  2ya
9   2xb  2yb
10  2xa  3ya
11  2xb  3yb
12  3xa  1ya
13  3xb  1yb
14  3xa  2ya
15  3xb  2yb
16  3xa  3ya
17  3xb  3yb
```

It is up to you, how you name the columns, if *x* and *y* don't satisfy you,
change them to whatever names you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the `itertools` package or do a search for it on this site.  There are a bunch of useful modules and examples.  What you describe above is a cartesian product of the 2 vectors which `itertools.product` does for you.

```
In [14]: from itertools import product                                          

In [15]: c1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'horse']                                           

In [16]: c2 = [22, 33, 44]                                                      

In [17]: for combo in product(c1, c2): 
    ...:     print (combo) 
    ...:                                                                        
('dog', 22)
('dog', 33)
('dog', 44)
('cat', 22)
('cat', 33)
('cat', 44)
('horse', 22)
('horse', 33)
('horse', 44)
```

If it is just 2 vectors, you could also "roll your own" with a list comprehension over the 2 vectors as such:

```
In [18]: result = [(x,y) for x in c1 for y in c2]                               

In [19]: result                                                                 
Out[19]: 
[('dog', 22),
 ('dog', 33),
 ('dog', 44),
 ('cat', 22),
 ('cat', 33),
 ('cat', 44),
 ('horse', 22),
 ('horse', 33),
 ('horse', 44)]
```

Of course, you should figure out what to do with the NaN's first....